# How to generate links from URLs in Draft.js using draft-js-utils stateToHTML()

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs

I have a web form for tasks. The description field of the is a Draft.js rich text editor. Once the form is submitted, the data is persisted to a DB. It renders in the UI as HTML in a card. The card can be edited inline. In edit mode, the persisted data prepopulates the original form as a Draft.js editor.

I just added the linkify plugin. I copied code from the example called "Themed Linkify Example" on this page: https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/linkify. I see that if I type something like "cnn.com" it makes a link in the editor. (it's actually an anchor tag with nested spans.) However, once I submit the form the rendered HTML is a paragraph, not a link. If I edit it, it displays as a link again in the Draft.js editor.

What would I change to make the link display an actual (clickable) link in the rendered card? Other formatting appears intact (for example, I can make bold text, lists, italics, etc) It's only the links that I'm having trouble with.

Here is the code for my editor. It's a bit long. In the `onChange()` function I added some console.log calls to shed light on what is happening. I typed the string `'cnn.com'` into the editor and here is the result of the console log calls:

```
"rawContent:" {
  "blocks": [
    {
      "key": "66gvt",
      "text": "cnn.com ",
      "type": "unstyled",
      "depth": 0,
      "inlineStyleRanges": [],
      "entityRanges": [],
      "data": {}
    }
  ],
  "entityMap": {}
}

htmlContent:"<p>cnn.com&nbsp;</p>"
```

Here is a screenshot of the markup as it appears **when the editor is open (create / edit mode)**

[image]

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react'
import {useStyletron} from 'baseui'
import {
    EditorState,
    RichUtils,
    getDefaultKeyBinding,
    ContentBlock,
    ContentState,
    DraftHandleValue,
    convertToRaw,
    convertFromHTML,
    RawDraftContentState,
} from 'draft-js'
import Editor from '@draft-js-plugins/editor'
import 'draft-js/dist/Draft.css'
import createLinkifyPlugin from '@draft-js-plugins/linkify'
import BlockStyleControls from './BlockStyleControls'
import InlineStyleControls from './InlineStyleControls'
import {stateToHTML} from 'draft-js-export-html'
import linkifyIt from 'linkify-it'
import tlds from 'tlds'

type Props = {
    setContent: (state: RawDraftContentState) => void
    setCount: (number) => void
    input: any,
    placeholder?: string | undefined
    initialValue?: string | undefined
}

const DraftEditor = ({setContent, setCount, input, placeholder, initialValue}: Props) => {
    const editorRef = useRef(null)
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(convertFromHTML(initialValue))))
    const [css] = useStyletron()

    const linkifyPlugin = createLinkifyPlugin({
        target: '_blank',
        component(props) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert, jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content
            return <a {...props} />;
        },
        customExtractLinks: (text) =>
            linkifyIt().tlds(tlds).set({ fuzzyEmail: false }).match(text),
    })

    const styleMap = {
        CODE: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)',
            fontFamily: '"Inconsolata", "Menlo", "Consolas", monospace',
            fontSize: 16,
            padding: 2,
        },
        STRIKETHROUGH: {
            textDecoration: 'line-through',
        },
    }

    const getBlockStyle = (block: ContentBlock) => {
        switch (block.getType()) {
            case 'blockquote':
                return 'RichEditor-blockquote'
            default:
                return ''
        }
    }

    const onChange = (state: EditorState) => {
        const rawContent = convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())
        const htmlContent = stateToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent())
        console.log(`rawContent: ${JSON.stringify(rawContent)}`)
        console.log(`htmlContent:${JSON.stringify(htmlContent)}`)
        setEditorState(state)
        setContent(rawContent)
        setCount(htmlContent.length)
        input.onChange(htmlContent)
    }

    const mapKeyToEditorCommand = (e: any): string | null => {
        if (e.keyCode === 9 /* TAB */) {
            const newEditorState = RichUtils.onTab(e, editorState, 4 /* maxDepth */)
            if (newEditorState !== editorState) {
                onChange(newEditorState)
            }
            return null
        }
        return getDefaultKeyBinding(e)
    }

    const handleKeyCommand = (
        command: string,
        editorState: EditorState,
        eventTimeStamp: number,
    ): DraftHandleValue => {
        const newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(editorState, command)
        if (newState) {
            onChange(newState)
            return 'handled'
        }
        return 'not-handled'
    }

    const toggleBlockType = (blockType: string) => {
        onChange(RichUtils.toggleBlockType(editorState, blockType))
    }

    const toggleInlineStyle = (inlineStyle: string) => {
        onChange(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(editorState, inlineStyle))
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className={css({
                border: '1px solid #dadada',
                padding: '3px',
                borderTopLeftRadius: '3px',
                borderTopRightRadius: '3px',
                background: 'white'
            })}>
                <InlineStyleControls
                    editorState={editorState}
                    onToggle={toggleInlineStyle}
                />
                <BlockStyleControls
                    editorState={editorState}
                    onToggle={toggleBlockType}
                />
            </div>
            <Editor
                ref={editorRef}
                editorState={editorState}
                customStyleMap={styleMap}
                blockStyleFn={(block: ContentBlock) => getBlockStyle(block)}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                plugins={[linkifyPlugin]}
                keyBindingFn={(e) => mapKeyToEditorCommand(e)}
                onChange={onChange}
                spellCheck={true}
                handleKeyCommand={handleKeyCommand}
            />
        </>
    )
}

export default React.memo(DraftEditor)
```

Comment: to use entity if you need inline style.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this. As per the source code above, I am using the `stateToHTML()` function exported from `draft-js-utils` to persist HTML. The question might be better phrased as "How do I convert a URL to a link using draft-js-utils stateToHTML()?".

I made the following functions:

```
const isLink = (text) => linkifyIt().tlds(tlds).set({fuzzyEmail: false}).match(text)

const renderLink = block => {
    if (isLink(block.getText())) {
        return `<a href="${block.getText()}" target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>${block.getText()}</a>`
    }
}
```

I pass `renderLink` as a `blockRenderer` in the options object: https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-utils/blob/master/packages/draft-js-export-html/README.md#blockrenderers